# configuring eclipse on ubuntu to use my jdk version

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to use eclipse on my installed jdk, which I thought should be simple to do in ubuntu (as it is in windows), but it turned out to be a surprisingly complex task. Firstly, the installations and running the eclipse are done like this:

```
$ which javac
/home/xx/jdk1.8.0_192/bin/javac
$ java -version
/home/xx/jdk1.8.0_192/bin/java
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/xx/jdk1.8.0_192
$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
$ /home/xx/eclipse.j/java-2018-09/eclipse/eclipse -vm /home/xx/jdk1.8.0_192/bin/java
```

eclipse-help-about shows the version as "2018-09 (4.9.0)", and when I see eclipse-help-about-installation_details-configure and search for -vm, shows that my specified jdk version is being used. And I am using ubuntu-18.04.

However, when I am creating a new project in eclipse, I am seeing that it still uses JRE System Library "java-11-openjdk-amd64". How do I change this to use my version of jdk? Do I need to set some more environment variables, do I need to configure eclipse in some other way?

I have looked at questions 16843976 and 3026897, but they are not really helping.

A second related question (after the above is answered): I have some extra jar files (eg for antlr) in a directory named /home/xx/jar. How do I tell eclipse to pick up the extra jars from this directory?

Comment: `-vm` is the JRE to run Eclipse, in _Window > Preference: Java > Installed JREs_ you can configure one or more JREs/JDKs to use for run/debug your applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure java on eclipse use 
`Look for Preferences and them search for Java -> Installed JREs`

Please find below screenshot for more information. If none is present Click `Add`
[image]

Also for extra jars add them to your Build path. Right click the `Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path`

Comment: I dont see "java" in properties in my (latest) version of eclipse (on ubuntu). I updated my question with a screenshot.

Comment: I added new jre in windows-pref-java-installed_jre, and entered the root of the jdk. Thanks.